How to disable/enable reactive form in the template dynamically?
I want to disable (or enable) a FormGroup based on a boolean input of my component
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  @Input() isDisabled: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
    // ...

All the answers that I found said it's bad practice to use <form [formGroup]="form" [disabled]="isDisabled" in the template, and to use this.form.disable(); in the typescript instead, most of them are also using old versions of Angular.
Is there any good solution to do this in the template and avoid extra code with a recent Angular (16+)?

You can write a reusable custom directive:
@Directive({
  selector: '[formGroup][formGroupDisabled]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class FormGroupDisabledDirective {
  /** Form group instance */
  @Input({ required: true }) formGroup?: FormGroup;
  /** Whether the form group is disabled or not */
  @Input({ required: true, transform: booleanAttribute })
  set formGroupDisabled(disabled: boolean) {
    if (!this.formGroup) {
      return;
    }
    if (disabled && this.formGroup.enabled) {
      this.formGroup.disable();
    } else if (!disabled && this.formGroup.disabled) {
      this.formGroup.enable();
    }
  }
}

And use it like the following in the template:
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" [formGroupDisabled]="someBooleanFlag">


I would suggest using input.required instead of @Input

@T.Jami The author asked for an Angular 16 solution, input.required does not exist in this version. Also it's still in developer preview.

16+, but yeah, my bad :)
